# Unable to map store's response to model - EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I am trying an ember application where I have installed Mirage and tried to fake the server. I am using a RestAdapter, the model is not getting the data from the response.

**adapters/application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
});
```

**contacts.js (Model)**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ContactModel from 'c360-app/models/contactsmodel';
export default ContactModel.extend({
    contactname: DS.attr(''),
    groupid: DS.attr(''),
    email: DS.attr(''),
    contactnumber: DS.attr('')
});
```

**all.js (route)**

```
import ContactRoute from 'c360-app/routes/contactsroute';
export default ContactRoute.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('contacts');
    }
});
```

**fixtures/contacts.js**

```
export default [  
    {
        contactname: 'Anusha Swaminathan',
        groupid: '12345',
        email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        contactnumber: '+91 12345',
        isFavourite: true,
        isIncomplete: false,
        isActive: true,
        hasAccess: true
    }, {
        contactname: 'Sriram Swaminathan',
        groupid: '12345',
        email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        contactnumber: '+91 12345',
        isFavourite: true,
        isIncomplete: false,
        isActive: true,
        hasAccess: true
    }, {
        contactname: 'Bhuvaneswari Swaminathan',
        groupid: '12345',
        email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        contactnumber: '+91 12345',
        isFavourite: false,
        isIncomplete: false,
        isActive: true,
        hasAccess: true
    }
];
```

**scenarios/default.js**

```
export default function( server ) {
   server.loadFixtures();
}
```

**Config.js (Mirage)**

```
export default function() {
  this.get('/contacts', function(db){
    return {contacts: db.contacts};
  });
}
```

**contact-listing.hbs**

```
    <table class = "contacts-table-header">
        <tr>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Group ID </th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th> 
        </tr>
{{#each model as |contact|}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{contact.contactname}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.groupid}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.contactnumber}}</td>
        </tr>

{{/each}}
</table>
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Pls guide. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you see any requests getting fired and any responses in your networking tab in developer tools? Also, do you use Ember inspector and can you see the model get populated with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all.js (route) You can try with return this.store.findAll('contact'); and model file name instead of contacts.js say contact.js

Comment: Ok, let me give a try. Will making the 'contacts' uncountable with Inflector work?